# What does a 'Build' in TFS consist of?

Tags: build, tfs

We currently use TFS 2010, however, it is mainly (95%) used for simple file version control.

Most of the projects we have are currently built and compiled in Visual Studio 6.  When we build one of these projects we create a DLL in VS6, however, there are about 5 other steps of other things that have to happen in order to do a 'full' build.

I'm wondering if I can combine these into some sort of TFS 'build' with a script or something else.

EDIT:

Extra steps include:
-Running another program to transform a text file into another type of file (the type is irrelevant and it is more the running of the program that is important.)
-Check files from the project into TFS
-Roll some build numbers contained in Folder Names/Other files
-Create zip file of Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are these steps that need to be done? TFS 2012 build process is customizable by templates and own written code so in fact you should be able to reduce the number of steps. More info on customizable templates can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms243782.aspx).